# (class,def,self) AttributeError: 'xx' object has no attribute 'xx'

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors

I become this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "xx", line 51, in

> Kontrolle.CheckSign()

File "xx", line 46, in CheckSign

> if self.isSigned == True:

AttributeError: 'Sicherheit' object has no attribute 'isSigned'

Can you help me?

```
import hashlib
class Sicherheit:
    passwordFile = 'usercreds.tmp'
    def Signup(self):
        self.isSigned = False # !!! self.isSigned
        print("Sie müssen sich erst anmelden!\n")
        usernameInput = input("Bitte geben Sie Ihren Nutzername ein: \n")
        passwordInput = input("Bitte geben Sie Ihr Passwort ein: \n")
        usernameInputHashed = hashlib.sha512(usernameInput.encode())
        passwordInputHashed = hashlib.sha512(passwordInput.encode())

        with open(self.passwordFile, 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(usernameInputHashed.hexdigest()))
            f.write('\n')
            f.write(str(passwordInputHashed.hexdigest()))
            f.close()

        self.isSigned = True  # !!! self.isSigned
        print("Anmeldung war erfolgreich!\n")
        print("======================================================\n")
        self.Login()  # Moves onto the login def

    def Login(self):
        print("Sie müssen sich einloggen!\n")

        usernameEntry = input("Bitte geben Sie Ihren Nutzername ein: \n")
        passwordEntry = input("Bitte geben Sie Ihr Passwort ein: \n")
        usernameEntry = hashlib.sha512(usernameEntry.encode())
        passwordEntry = hashlib.sha512(passwordEntry.encode())
        usernameEntryHashed = usernameEntry.hexdigest()
        passwordEntryHashed = passwordEntry.hexdigest()

        with open(self.passwordFile) as r:
            info = r.readlines()
            usernameInFile = info[0].rstrip()
            passwordInFile = info[1].rstrip()

        if usernameEntryHashed == usernameInFile and passwordEntryHashed == passwordInFile:
            print("Anmeldung war erfolgreich!\n")

        else:
            print("Anmeldung war nicht erfolgreich!!!\n")
            self.Login()

    def CheckSign(self):
        if self.isSigned == True:  # !!! self.isSigned
            self.Login()
        else:
            self.Signup()
Kontrolle = Sicherheit()
Kontrolle.CheckSign()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line

```
self.isSigned = False # !!! self.isSigned
```

out of your `SignUp` method and into your class variables or else create an `__init__` method for your class and initialise it in there

When you call:

```
Kontrolle = Sicherheit()
```

the code that sets your variable `self.isSigned` is not ever executed (it's part of the `SignUp` method and this is not executed) so when you call:

```
Kontrolle.CheckSign()
```

it looks for a variable which has not yet been set and then it throws the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Sicherheit' object has no attribute 'isSigned'
```

Here's how you declare it inside your class:

```
class Sicherheit:
    passwordFile = 'usercreds.tmp'

    def __init__(self):
        self.isSigned = False

    def SignUp():
        ....

    ....
```

Comment: how can i initialise it in there?